# GLASSFISH 3 DOMAIN SERVICE ERROR

Tags: glassfish-3

I installed GLASSFISH on Windows 2012 server.
I create a domain using the file asadmin.bat
The service and domain is created fine.
But after try to start-domain domain1 i received the next error:

```
at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.addExtensionBundle(Extens
ionManager.java:401)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2751)
        ... 13 more

Oct 20, 2014 2:40:39 AM BundleProvisioner install WARNING: Failed to
install file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/glassfish-corba
-omgapi.jar org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not create bundle object.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2785)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleCont
extImpl.java:165)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.install
(BundleProvisioner.java:446)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.install
Bundles(BundleProvisioner.java:208)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuild
er.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:139)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime
.java:157)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.
java:110)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(
GlassFishMain.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMa
in.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.addExtensionBundle(Extens
ionManager.java:401)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2751)
        ... 13 more

Oct 20, 2014 2:40:39 AM BundleProvisioner install WARNING: Failed to
install file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/glassfish-extra
-jre-packages.jar org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not create bundle object.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2785)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleCont
extImpl.java:165)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.install
(BundleProvisioner.java:446)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.install
Bundles(BundleProvisioner.java:208)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuild
er.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:139)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime
.java:157)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.
java:110)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(
GlassFishMain.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMa
in.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.addExtensionBundle(Extens
ionManager.java:401)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2751)
        ... 13 more

Oct 20, 2014 2:40:39 AM BundleProvisioner install WARNING: Failed to
install file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/glassfish-oracl
e-jdbc-driver-packages.jar org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could
not create bundle object.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2785)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleCont
extImpl.java:165)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.install
(BundleProvisioner.java:446)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.install
Bundles(BundleProvisioner.java:208)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuild
er.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:139)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime
.java:157)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.
java:110)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(
GlassFishMain.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMa
in.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.addExtensionBundle(Extens
ionManager.java:401)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2751)
        ... 13 more

Oct 20, 2014 2:40:39 AM BundleProvisioner install WARNING: Failed to
install file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/javax.transacti on.jar
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not create bundle object.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2785)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleCont
extImpl.java:165)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.install
(BundleProvisioner.java:446)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.install
Bundles(BundleProvisioner.java:208)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuild
er.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:139)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime
.java:157)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.
java:110)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(
GlassFishMain.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMa
in.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.addExtensionBundle(Extens
ionManager.java:401)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2751)
        ... 13 more

Oct 20, 2014 2:40:39 AM BundleProvisioner install WARNING: Failed to
install file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/webservices-ext
ra-jdk-packages.jar org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not
create bundle object.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2785)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleCont
extImpl.java:165)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.install
(BundleProvisioner.java:446)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.install
Bundles(BundleProvisioner.java:208)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuild
er.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:139)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime
.java:157)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.
java:110)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(
GlassFishMain.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMa
in.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.addExtensionBundle(Extens
ionManager.java:401)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2751)
        ... 13 more

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle
jaxb-api [2] : Unable to resolve 2.0: missing requirement [2.0]
osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wi ring.package=javax.activation)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:382
6)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1868)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1191)

        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStart
LevelImpl.java:295)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle
org.glassfis h.metro.webservices-api-osgi [3]: Unable to resolve 3.0:
missing requirement [3. 0] osgi.wiring.package;
(&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.bind)(version>=2.2.0)) [caused by:
Unable to resolve 2.0: missing requirement [2.0] osgi.wiring.package ;
(osgi.wiring.package=javax.activation)]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:382
6)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1868)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1191)

        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStart
LevelImpl.java:295)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/osgi/framework/BundleActivator
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.findCla
ss(BundleWiringImpl.java:2128)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDele
gation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1432)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringIm
pl.java:72)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadCla
ss(BundleWiringImpl.java:1843)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.getClassByDelegation(Bund
leWiringImpl.java:1317)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.createBundleActivator(Felix.java:417
0)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:1972)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1895)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1191)

        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStart
LevelImpl.java:295)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator
not found by org.glassfish.main.core.glassfish [101]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDele
gation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1460)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringIm
pl.java:72)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadCla
ss(BundleWiringImpl.java:1843)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 14 more org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.glassfis h.hk2.osgi-adapter [203]: Unable to
resolve 203.0: missing requirement [203.0] o sgi.wiring.package;
(&(osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.enterprise.module)(version>=1 .1.0))
[caused by: Unable to resolve 121.0: missing requirement [121.0]
osgi.wir ing.package;
(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.jvnet.hk2.config)(version>=1.1.0)) [caus ed
by: Unable to resolve 37.0: missing requirement [37.0]
osgi.wiring.package; ( osgi.wiring.package=javax.management)]]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:382
6)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1868)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1191)

        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStart
LevelImpl.java:295)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMa
in.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
Caused by: org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishException:
org.glassfish.embeddable .GlassFishException: No GlassFishRuntime
available
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuild
er.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:164)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime
.java:157)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.
java:110)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(
GlassFishMain.java:112)
        ... 6 more Caused by: org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishException: No GlassFishRuntime avai
lable
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuild
er.getGlassFishRuntime(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:202)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuild
er.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:162)
        ... 9 more Error stopping framework: java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher$1.run(G
lassFishMain.java:203) Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring
option MaxPermSize=192m; support wa s removed in 8.0 Java HotSpot(TM)
Client VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=64m; support was re moved
in 8.0

Command start-domain failed. asadmin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Java JDK7 (I believe you're using a newer JDK version);

Follow Oracle's [Release Notes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24939/toc.htm) for the supported JDK versions.